# Chrome window all screwed up after locking or disconnecting second monitor?

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager

I've noticed that when I unlock my computer or disconnect a second monitor, about 25% of the time my chrome window will resize itself to about 100 pixels tall and position itself at the top of the screen.  When it does there I have no way of resizing it or accessing any of the pages.  Even if I drag one of the tabs out to it's own window it will have the same problem.  I always end up quitting Chrome to solve the problem.

Does anyone know of a fix for this problem?  If not, does anyone know of a way that I can make Chrome accessible without having to quit out of it?

Comment: Please explain the 2 non related activity in more details. Unlock computer? disconnect 2nd monitor (how?)

Comment: I don't think I understand the question?  Are you asking me how I disconnect a second monitor?  I unplug it from my laptop.  To unlock my computer I type in my password.  Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thank you, it is clearer now. Does it work without using the screen lock.

Comment: Yeah Chrome hums along just fine until I lock the computer usually.